# Yocto Project (Gatesgarth) SDK build fails due to missing repositries: do_fetch: Fetcher failure

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer

I am building the yocto SDK (Gatesgarth) for zedboard but it fails due to missing several repositories as "do_fetch: Failed". Here are the error details.

> ERROR: qtsvg-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+52d3788c7b-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtsvg.git;name=qtsvg;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

> ERROR: qtxmlpatterns-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+50421402f0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtxmlpatterns.git;name=qtxmlpatterns;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

> ERROR: qtquickcontrols2-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+16f27dfa35-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git;name=qtquickcontrols2;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

> ERROR: qtbase-native-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+40143c189b-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git;name=qtbase;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

> ERROR: qtdeclarative-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+104eae5b17-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git;name=qtdeclarative;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

> ERROR: qtbase-5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+40143c189b-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git;name=qtbase;branch=5.15.2;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

Is there any solution to this issue? I am able to clone the repositories. i.e. there should be no issue accessing the URL. I am including the "qt5-git.inc" for reference. Do I need to edit it for branch correction?

```
#######Copyright (C) 2012-2016 O.S. Systems Software LTDA.
########Copyright (C) 2013-2020 Martin Jansa <martin.jansa@gmail.com>
QT_MODULE ?= "${BPN}"
QT_MODULE_BRANCH ?= "5.15.2"
QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM ?= "branch=${QT_MODULE_BRANCH}"

####### each module needs to define valid SRCREV
SRC_URI = " \
    ${QT_GIT}/${QT_MODULE}.git;name=${QT_MODULE};${QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM};protocol=${QT_GIT_PROTOCOL} \
"

CVE_PRODUCT = "qt"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

PV = "5.15.2+git${SRCPV}"
```

Comment: Branch `5.15.2` doesn't seem to exist (anymore, at least). You could switch to `5.15` branch, and/or use the revision directly that corresponds to tag `5.15.2`